# Pass a List to a Function to act as Multiple Arguments in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, parameter-passing, parameter-pack

In Python, we can unpack a list to pass the elements of the list as arguments to a function. I am looking for a similar feature in C++.

I have a list of unknown size and a function which has number of arguments == size of list. I want to unpack this list and pass the elements as arguments to this functions. Below is a sample code:

```
#include <cstdio>

void yourFunction(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", b);
    printf("%d\n", c);
    printf("%d\n", d);
    printf("%d\n", e);
}

int main() {
    int inputList[5] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}; // size of list can be unknown at compile time
    // Somehow pass this list to function as individual elements
}
```

I tried some methods in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack but I can't figure the solution to the above problem.

Comment: What you want to do is impossible in C++, because the arguments of a function call must be fixed at compile time. Your only option is to pass the list of --unknown size-- a size only known at runtime as list to the function.

Comment: I find it strange that Python has a very simple feature to support this, but C++ does not. Is there any fundamental difference between C++ and Python which is causing this difference?

Comment: Yes there are a lot of differences between C++ and Python. Some of them quite fundamental. To begin with, C++ is a compiled language whereas Python is not.

Comment: And what is the use case for this?

Comment: If you don't know the size of your list at compile time, the best you can do is a helper function that will call `yourFunction(list[0], list[1], list[2] ...);` in a way dependent on the `list.size()`. I assume you have some finite and predefined amount of `yourFunctions`.

Comment: If you wonder how this is done in Python: By passing everything as arrays and dictionaries of `PyObject*` into functions and having lots of boilerplate around those calls to make this as transparent to the Python dev as possible. You may get an idea if you take a look at [the C-API documentation for function calls](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/call.html#object-calling-api). It is not possible to reproduce this with a few lines of C++ code.

Comment: @kiner_shah I am working on a framework which receives inputs as a list and is responsible for passing these inputs to a dynamically loaded library. This library can be different on each execution, but the input list is guaranteed to match the function arguments.

Comment: @pptaszni Unfortunately no. See my comment above. `yourFunction` is dynamic and can be different on each execution. And the set of functions is not known beforehand.

Comment: fwiw, for your framework, I am certain that there are solutions in c++ that do not require you to pass an array to `yourFunc`. Don't expect languages to offer same solutions to same problems. I would suggest to open another quesiton where you tell us about what you actually want to achieve, not only about the way you think you could achieve it.